# error: 'length.out' must be a non-negative number

Tags: r

when i am doing this with arguments in my script this cause an error

```
pief <- function(coll, largs1,largs2, collor1,collor2,title){
summary(subset(delete, select = c(released, sex, citizen)))
pie_labels <- paste0(round(100 * table(delete$coll)/sum(table(delete$coll)), 2), "%" )
pie(table(delete$coll), 
    labels = c(pie_labels, largs1,largs2),
    col = c(collor2, collor1),
    main = title)
legend("topleft", legend = c(largs1,largs2), fill = c(collor1, collor2))
}
pief(sex, "Male","Female","Blue","Pink", "Gender")
```

the problem is in the coll argument.

How i can fix this?

I tried soo much staff from changing the table to something else, to remake the script

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. You should call your function with `pief("sex", ....)` and then use `delete[[coll]]` rather than `delete$coll`. Basically a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/dynamically-select-data-frame-columns-using-and-a-character-value

Comment: thank you very much